# How to Automatically Tell What is Not Tested

Tags: testing, verification, formal-methods

I feel like I've heard the phrase "Automated Test Coverage" but not really sure what it means. I am wondering if there is a way to do some sort of program analysis that will tell you which parts of your code are untested. In this way, figure out what is left to test to build a robust system.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your programming language, but what are are looking for is a code coverage tool Just run it on your tests.

https://stackify.com/code-coverage-tools/

Comment: There are also tools that match code changes in a particular pull request with coverage output, showing what's in the new / changed code is tested or not.

Comment: Note: code coverage tools tell you what code is executed. If you use a code coverage tool during your tests, it tells you which code was executed by your tests. It does *not* tell you which code was *tested* by your tests. It can only tell you what code was *definitely not* tested, namely the one that wasn't even executed. Simple proof: take a test suite with 100% code coverage. Remove all assertions, otherwise keep the tests as is. Run again: still 100% code coverage but *nothing* is tested.